# Only Updated the field in MongoDB edited by the user on the front-end

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

My web app is based on the MEAN Stack and within the app users can edit their details after registration such as name, address, contact number etc. Currently what I am doing is that I get the `ID` of the logged in user can find the user within MongoDB using `findByIdAndUpdate` and then update the whole user document.

If the user only updates their contact number the users document in the database still completely overwritten. Please not that I don't lose any data this way, when I say overwritten I mean just to update the users contact number I push the whole user object to the database that I got on login but with the amended contact details and I overwrite the previous whole document with the my current one.

This seems wrong, how can I only update the field that the user edited within the form. I can't predict what field they will edit because that depends on the user.

Heres my code below:

```
 User.findOneAndUpdate({userID: req.params.id},{
                name: req.body.name, // The user didn't update this but I am still pushing it to the database because I can't predict whether they updated this or not
                email: req.body.email, // The user didn't update this but I am still pushing it to the database because I can't predict whether they updated this or not
                contactNumber: req.body.contactNumber // This the field the user actually wanted to update
            }, function(err, user){
                    if(err){
                        console.log("The erroris " + err);
                    }
                    else if(user){

                        console.log("user edited");

                    }    
                });
```

If you need more info to answer please let me know.
Thank you

Comment: If the whole fields are editable -the user can change them- then you have to save the whole thing. Unless you want to do something to check which fields changed.

Comment: @user1655756 thanks for the comment, is saving the whole document bad practice if the user only wanted to edit 1 or 2 or 3 fields?

Comment: I am not really sure to be honest. But if you don't want to do that you will have to implement something to check modified fields, for which you will have to fetch the original record again... I would leave it that way. Anyway, make sure mongo suits your needs. I made a huge system only to find out I would be better of with sql. Really poor analysis.

Comment: @user1655756 Thanks for the info! Mongo seems okay so far, my whole depends on API because its deployed across multiple platforms and Mongo seems to be a good backend for API's.